# GridView does not display headers

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, listview, gridview

I have a `ListView` where the `GridView.ColumnHeaderTemplate` is:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
    <TextBlock />
</DataTemplate>
```

But when I add new columns the header does not display any text:

```
GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn();
column.Header = new TextBlock { Text = "my header" };
MyGridView.Columns.Add(column);
```

Why? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget to add Text property binding?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need the `ColumnHeaderTemplate` to be declared explicitly since by default its the textBlock? Just get rid of the template and change your code-behind to this -

```
GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn();
column.Header = "my header";
MyGridView.Columns.Add(column);
```

Simply `set your string to the Header` property.

**EDIT**

In case you want to play with background and font styles, you need to keep the textBlock. So, keep the code behind as suggested above i.e just set the header with the string and in your xaml bind text property -

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Background="Red" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: In this way your column.Header is a string, not a TextBlock. And i can't change the Background or the FontFamily (for example).